# X is a continuous random variable with $Y = (X − 3)^2$

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X$ follows $N(0,1)$ what is the mgf of Y?

I think I found that the pdf of Y is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2y\pi}}e^{(\sqrt{y}+3)t}e^{\frac{-(\sqrt{y}+3)^2}{2}}$

Then I think you're supposed to integrate but the integral doesn't work out well.

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your work into the question body.

Comment: what is the definition of mgf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition, $$\begin{aligned}M_Y(t):=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{Yt}\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{(X-3)^2t}\right]=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{t(x-3)^2}e^{-\frac12x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{e^{9t+\frac{18 t^2}{1-2 t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\frac12\left[(1-2t)x^2+12tx+\frac{36 t^2}{1-2 t}\right]}dx\\
&=\frac{e^{\frac{9 t}{1-2 t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\frac12\left[x\sqrt{1-2t}+\frac{6 t}{\sqrt{1-2 t}}\right]^2}dx\\
\end{aligned}$$
now let $u=x\sqrt{1-2t}$,
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{e^{\frac{9 t}{1-2 t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\frac12\left[x\sqrt{1-2t}+\frac{6 t}{\sqrt{1-2 t}}\right]^2}dx&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-2t}}e^{\frac{9 t}{1-2 t}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12\left[u-\frac{-6 t}{\sqrt{1-2 t}}\right]^2}du\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-2t}}e^{\frac{9 t}{1-2 t}}\cdot1=\frac1{\sqrt{1-2t}}e^{\frac{9 t}{1-2 t}},\,\,t<\frac12.
\end{aligned}$$